# Is it ok to access IsolatedStorage in ViewModels when following MVVM pattern?

Tags: mvvm, windows-phone-8

i am trying to understand is it ok to access Isolated storage in a ViewModel in a Windows Phone or Windows 8 projects?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why not. The purpose of MVVM is breaking the dependance between the UI and the business logic. The isolated storage isn't UI-related, so it's perfectly fine to use in the viewmodel.